# Created a pong game following a youtube tutorial in Python, then wanted to increase ball speed after goal scored?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, pong

I wanted to increase the speed of the ball after each "goal" scored, you can see under #1 and #2 are points where I have tried and failed to do this, speedx and speedy was orignally just

Firstly I tried to increase by adding on to the already defined if loop in the tutorial, the #1 is what I added on the end

```
if ball.xcor() > 390:
    ball.goto(0, 0)
    ball.dx *= -1
    score_a += 1
    pen.clear()
    pen.write("Big Man : {} Pussio: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))
   #1 speedy += 0.1
   #1 speedx += 0.1
   #1 ball.dx = speedx
   #1 ball.dy = speedy
```

I then tried to make my own for loop, however the problem I have is when I increase the speed, it will always make the ball go in a (x,y) (+,+) direction after a goal is scored, i think because I am adding +1 to the ball.dx it sets the ball in a (+, +) direction, when as you can see from my code, after a goal is scored i want to reverse the starting direction, using:

```
if ball.xcor() > 390:
    ball.goto(0, 0)
    ball.dx *= -1          - this
    score_a += 1
```

so basically i want to increase the speed of the ball in increments everytime a goal is scored and also I want to keep the ball going in different directions after scoring,
Here is the for loop i tried and also got no luck with

```
#2if ball.xcor() < -390 or ball.xcor() > 390:
#2 ball.dx = speedx
#2 ball.dy = speedy
#2 speedy *= -1
#2 speedx *= -1
#2 speedy += 0.1
#2 speedx += 0.1
```

Maybe this cant be done the speed increment as turtle is too basic I'm not sure?

Below is full code:

Answer (score 0):

To accelerate the ball, the simplest way is probably to multiply `dx` and `dy` by a `factor > 1` (to decrease it, use a `0 < factor < 1`) :

In this example, the velocity is increased by 10%.

```
acc_factor = 1.1
...
dx *= acc_factor
dy *= acc_factor
```

If you want a fixed increment, you can do like this:

```
acc_factor = 1.1
...
dx_increment = abs(dx)/dx * acc_factor
dx += dx_increment
dy_increment = abs(dy)/dy * acc_factor
dy += dy_increment
```

Answer (score 0):

You should introduce time to make this easier as the game gets more complex.
`self.vx` should be equal to `self.dx * unit_of_time`. You can then increment `self.vx` over time in order to introduce acceleration. Note that if accelleration is constantly changing, you might also want to add `self.ax` to control accelleration more easily.